# Editing Access Database with ADODC and Datagrid

Tags: datagrid, vb6, ado

I have a database connected to my vb program. One of the forms in the project edits the information in the database. The Form works by searching for a student first, showing the student at the top of the database and then edits the information. the problem is when the information is edited, it edits the first row in the database, not the one chosen (it kind of replaces it). So how do i code it so it can edit only that particular row and not the first one from the database? The Code:

```
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
  With frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset
  .Fields(1) = txtFirstName.Text
  .Fields(2) = txtLastName.Text
  .Fields(3) = txtMarks(0).Text
  .Fields(4) = txtMarks(1).Text
  .Fields(5) = txtMarks(2).Text
  .Update
  frmStudents.StudentTable.Refresh '.DataSource = frmStudents.Adodc1
  End With
  MsgBox "Student Updated Successfully", vbInformation, "Success"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As a hint: where do you select a specific record for update? So what do you think will happen, if you have - lets say .... 3 records? Or oven worse: No record?

Comment: I have another form that shows the students and outlines whether the information is there or not and a function to see if there is a record or not. @nabuchodonossor

Comment: ok, but what I try to tell you: When your recordset contains exactly one record, you code is ok. But if record Count <> 1, then your code is wrong, because you never move your recordpointer

Comment: Thats correct, I didn't even think of that. So have do you suggest I do it.

Comment: You could iterate through your recordset collection and check the primary key for equality (or any other unique key you may have). You do this by using a loop and the movenext method and the eof property (for checking if your at the end)

Comment: Or you can submi an update statement ... but you would still need an primary key (or at least an unique key to your record)

Comment: I have an ID for every student as the primary key.

Comment: as first step, write a loop through your records and update only the record you should (you can exit the loop after update, not need to check the other ids)

Comment: which form do i do it in. The edit form or the search form.

Comment: I´m guessing - I don´t know your application: You have a search window, you select a record for edit (at this time you should know your id) and open an edit form, then you have a save and a cancel button, and on save you should update your db. That can be done by SQL (update statement) or make a search on your table with the id (should found one record) and then update it (as your original source did). Or you have somewhere you recordset and you loop through it. I suggest reading about loops, recordset methods, SQL.

Comment: i have a search window, you select a record for edit (at this time you should know your id) and open an edit form, then you have a save and a cancel button, and on save you should update your db